# Need to get FileSize via SSIS Package Task

Tags: ssis, filesize

I have an SSIS package that im building in BIDS. Currently my control flow pulls a Uri and Folder Destination out of a table, downloads the Uri to the given destination. What I would like to do is update that table with the filesize. the source table looks like this:

SourceUri | SourceName | Destination | Date | DownloadCount| FileSize

I've tried to get the filesize via the Uri Headers but it doesn't seem to work, is there a Task i could add that would get the filesize for my downloaded uri ( i already have the filename and the destination in variables) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of `System.IO.FileInfo` to get the file size from within SSIS `Script Task`. Following example shows how this can be achieved. The example was created in `SSIS 2008 R2`.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. On the SSIS package's connection create an OLE DB connection to connect to the SQL Server as shown in screenshot #**1**. I have named the connection as **SQLServer**.
2. In the SQL Server database, create a table named `dbo.Downloads` and populate with records using the scripts given under **SQL Scripts** section. Screenshot #**2** shows data in the table.
3. On the SSIS package, create 8 variables as shown in screenshot #**3**. Set the variable **LocalFolder** with value `c:\temp\`. Set the variable **SQLGetData** with value `SELECT Id, SourceUri, SourceName FROM dbo.Downloads`. Set the variable **SQLUpdate** with value `UPDATE dbo.Downloads SET Destination = ?, Date = GETDATE(), DownloadCount = COALESCE(DownloadCount, 0) + 1, FileSize = ? WHERE Id = ?`.
4. On the package's Control Flow tab, place an Execute SQL Task, Foreach loop container, and Script Task & Execute SQL Task within Foreach Loop container as shown in screenshot #**4**.
5. Configure the first Execute SQL Task named 'Get data' as shown in screenshots #**5** and #**6**. This task with fetch the records and store it in an Object variable.
6. Configure the Foreach Loop container as shown in screenshots #**7** and #**8**. This task will loop through the resultset.
7. Replace the Main() method within the script task with the code provided under the **Script Task Code** section. The code uses the `System.IO.FileInfo` object to fetch the file size after it has been downloaded.
8. Configure the second Execute SQL Task named 'Update' as shown in screenshots #**9** and #**10**. This task will update the database after the file downloads.
9. Screenshot #**11** shows that the folder path `C:\temp\` is empty **before** the package execution.
10. Screenshot #**12** shows package execution.
11. Screenshot #**13** shows that the folder path `C:\temp\` contains the downloaded contents **after** the package execution.
12. Screenshot #**14** shows data in table dbo.Downloads after package execution. Screenshots #**15** and #**16** show the properties of the downloaded files. Note the file size updated in the table with the file size on the properties dialog. **`NOTE`**: System.IO.File will fetch only the Size and **not** Size on disk. The file size updated in the database table is in **bytes**.
13. Screenshot #**17** shows that the folder path `C:\temp\` contains the downloaded contents **after** the **second** package execution. Note the **DownloadCount** value.

Hope that helps.

**SQL Scripts:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Downloads](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SourceUri] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [SourceName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Destination] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [DownloadCount] [int] NULL,
    [FileSize] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Downloads] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Downloads (SourceUri, SourceName) VALUES
('http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/', 'logo1w.png'),
('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/', 'Wikipedia-logo.png');
GO
```

**Script task code:**

**C#** code that can be used only in **`SSIS 2008 and above`**.

```
public void Main()
{
    Variables varCollection = null;

    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::SourceUri");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::SourceName");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::LocalFolder");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::Destination");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::FileSize");
    Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

    System.Net.WebClient myWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string sourceUri = varCollection["User::SourceUri"].Value.ToString();
    string sourceName = varCollection["User::SourceName"].Value.ToString();
    string webResource = sourceUri + sourceName;
    string fileName = varCollection["User::LocalFolder"].Value.ToString() + sourceName;
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(webResource, fileName);

    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(fileName);
    varCollection["User::Destination"].Value = fileName;
    varCollection["User::FileSize"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(fileInfo.Length);

    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

**Screenshot #15:**

[image: 15]

**Screenshot #16:**

[image: 16]

**Screenshot #17:**

[image: 17]

Answer (score 1):

After downloading the file, you can use a script task to get the file size or any other information you need using the standard .NET [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) class and save it to a package variable.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did it this way, and also update the database in the same script