# SSIS FTP file name and file sizes list

Tags: ssis, ftp, script-task

We use the **`FTP task`** in **`SSIS`** to download about 500 files from an FTP server, with the biggest file about 2 Gigabytes in size. The download fails 50% of the time. We would like to implement a step in our **`SSIS`** package that would retrieve the list of files on the **`FTP Server`** and the file sizes before we try download them for processing. The **`FTP Task`** doesn't have an operation that retrieves the file list and the file sizes. Can you provide an example of how to do this?

Below is the **`Script Task`** code block I've found to retrieve the file name list and store in an XML file.

```
    Dim ftpFileNameListXML As New StringBuilder
    ftpFileNameListXML.AppendLine("<filelist>")

    Dim ftpcm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTP")
    Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = _
                New FtpClientConnection(ftpcm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))
    Dim ftpFileNames() As String
    Dim ftpFolderNames() As String

    ftp.Connect()
    ftp.SetWorkingDirectory(Dts.Variables("FtpWorkingDirectory").Value.ToString())
    ftp.GetListing(ftpFolderNames, ftpFileNames)
    ftp.Close()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ftpFileNames.GetUpperBound(0)
        ftpFileNameListXML.Append("<file name='")
        ftpFileNameListXML.Append(ftpFileNames(i))
        ftpFileNameListXML.AppendLine("'/>")
    Next i

    ftpFileNameListXML.AppendLine("</filelist>")
    Dts.Variables("FtpFileListXML").Value = ftpFileNameListXML.ToString()

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

Comment: May you post the specific execution errors you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698448/need-to-get-filesize-via-ssis-package-task

Comment: I'm not getting any errors, I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve the file size.

Comment: Look at the above link I posted

Comment: I've looked at the example already but it doesn't solve my issues. I want to retrieve the ftp file names and sizes, which I'll use for validation at a later stage. The files will be downloaded at a later stage after I've retrieved the file sizes.

Comment: Is your script not working? Or do you not know how to implement it in SSIS?

Comment: The script works correctly, and I can list all filenames on the FTP server. I'm struggling to find a method / way to get the file sizes.

Comment: I just added the answer I believe you seek

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to get the file sizes in VB:  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/205915/VB-NET-get-the-size-of-a-file-Downloading-in-FTP-S

"You should use the GetFileSize[^] field to know in advance the selected file size."

`Dim ftp As Net.FtpWebRequest = GetRequest(URI)

 ftp.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize`

Her is another link http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/317225-want-to-get-ftp-server-file-name-fil-size-in-listview/

Try using `ListDirectoryDetails`

Comment: Yes the script works correctly, and I can list all filenames on the FTP server. I'm struggling to find a method / way to get the file sizes. How do I get the file sizes?

Comment: did you add a `Script Task` to your control flow?

Comment: Yes, the above code runs successfully on a Script Task and I can list all file names on the FTP server.

Comment: I found this link to get file size:  http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/205915/VB-NET-get-the-size-of-a-file-Downloading-in-FTP-S  Sorry about the confusion "You should use the GetFileSize[^] field to know in advance the selected file size."